# question mark icons replacing picture when xcode project is loaded

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, xcode10

Sometimes when I open an xcode project, some UI Image elements are shown as question mark icons instead of the real picture, like:
[image]

I'm curious as to why that is the case and want to know if there is a way to fix this. The pictures are loaded correctly in the simulation:
[image]

But having the right pictures in main.storyboard would certainly help a lot. Especially to work in the UI before running the simulations, if the view controller has tons of UI Images on it.

Here are some details:

- Xcode 10
- Mac mini (late 2012), 16 Gb DDR3
- macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
- I downloaded this projects from a github repository (the pictures were already included)
- The simulation displayed no errors

Regards,

FS

Comment: remove Drived data ,  clean project `cmd + shift + k`   open storyboard fixit for me.

Comment: It can happen because of indexing issue. It happens more frequently in Xcod10 for me.